# Order by date desc, but within day order by time asc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which there is a `Date` (smalldatetime) column. I need to `order by Date DESC`, but within each day to `order by Date ASC`.  The output should be like:

```
Date
2017-01-31T09:00:00Z
2017-01-31T17:00:00Z
2017-01-28T09:00:00Z
2017-01-28T17:00:00Z
2017-01-25T09:00:00Z
2017-01-25T17:00:00Z
...
```

Is such a query possible?

If it's of any help, the data contains a maximum of two rows for the same `Date`.

Comment: Plz tag your RDBMS. Your question title itself is the solution of your question, what you need is the specific function (of RDBMS) to extract day and time from your date column.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. I am using Microsoft SQL Server, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to `date`and then to `time`

```
ORDER BY 
    CAST([Date] AS date) DESC
    ,CAST([Date] AS time) ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am curious why `ORDER BY Date DESC, CAST([Date] as time) ASC` does not work.

Comment: Well, it won't work because it will first sort by the entire date field(inculding the time) and then on those that are the same will continue to the next sorting, which obviously won't have any effect. i hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY DATE(`date`) DESC, TIME(`date`) ASC;
I hope my answer can help you!

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:sql-server]. I see no [`DATE` or `TIME` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql#GetDateandTimeParts)

Comment: Yes, I get `Error Message: 'Date' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: i'm so sorry，it's function of mysql